Nuget: Suppress NU1605 in CLI
I have released a large version of company library. Before creating a tag, I would like to check its functionality.
To do this, I packed all the projects that it consists of and put them in a folder.
Now I want to run autotests on a project that uses my version of library.
To do this, I should change all the manifests (.csproj's) by changing the version of this library from the release one to 0.0.0-local. However, I was unable to do this through Rider or VS.
I inherited the following command
Get-Package | ?{ $_.Id -like 'Company.Common*'; } | %{ Update-Package -ProjectName $_.ProjectName -Id $_.Id -Source "D:\Projects\Local Nugets" -Version 0.0.0-local; }


However, I am unable to install this version due to NU1605 - the high connectivity of packages among themselves.
Is there a way to suppress it?
Of course, I can use Far for these purposes, but is there a good solution?
